# M5 model in ensemble

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, ensemble-learning

I am using the M5 model implemented in the `RWeka` package for predicting a continues variable based on several independent, ecological variables.

```
model  <- M5P(T_apr  ~ ., data=train)
```

I would like to use this to further build an ensemble model in R, but I'm having difficulties finding a way how to do this. Therefore my question: how to build an ensemble using M5 models in R?

Comment: You should probably state *which* ensemble method you want to utilize (model averaging, bagging, boosting, ...), and take a look at the `caret` package and [`caretEnsemble`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caretEnsemble/vignettes/caretEnsemble-intro.html). Be aware that ensemble building should be part of the training+evaluation process.

Comment: It isn't clear to me if you're asking a conceptual question about ensembles or a coding question (how to implement them in R). Note that the latter is off-topic here, see our [help/on-topic]

Comment: My question is conceptual, to get a direction. I tried `ipred` package, but it works with regression trees, where leafs are constants.  I need to work with M5, where leafs are represented by regression models.
I didn’t state, which ensemble method I want, because I want to test more than just one (I know bagging, boosting and Random Forest). But I could start with bagging.
I will go through `caretEnsamble` package and come back to you with my feedback. If there is any other suggestion, I am open for it.

Answer (score 0):

After some time, I am able to answer my own question.

> library("RWeka")
>   mybag= Bagging(T_apr  ~ ., data=train, control =
>   Weka_control(W = M5P))

For further optimization options see:

> WOW(Bagging)